# Nested DIV tag overflows Parent DIV tag

Tags: asp.net, css

Having problem with the parent DIV tag being stationary, as noticed with background coloring.

CSS:

```
div
{
  postion:absolute;
}
...
#divBody
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    left: 20%;
    right: 10%;
    top: 110px;
    width:70%; min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
...
div .Registration
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div .QA
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

root.master

```
  <div id="divBody" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server" />
  </div>
```

root.aspx

```
<div id="divReg" style="visibility: visible;" class="Registration" runat="server">
  ...
</div>
<div id="divQA" style="visibility: hidden;" class="QA" runat="server">
  <table id="tblContent" class="tblQA" runat="server" />
  ...
</div>
```

- HTML Table object is only declared here as a placeholder, it is filled in the codebehind through data connectors and iterations.

Screen Capture:

[image: Child Div tag overflows Parent]

#### Question:

How do i get the parent DIV tag to expand with the child DIV tag?

Comment: would be easier to troubleshoot with some actual markup to troubleshoot - is it possible to make a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you're seeing?

Comment: @kinakuta well there is the screen cap of what is going on.  Dont really need alot cause i have isolated it to one of three CSS elements.

Comment: A jsfiddle really would be exceptionally helpful in this case.  I can't tell in the markup and CSS which elements are the parent and the child.  In your markup, I see a div called "divReg", followed by a sibling called "divQA".  "divQA" contains a table called "tblContent".  I just cannot tell exactly what is going on without a fiddle or more code.

Comment: So how would i load ASP.Net into JSFiddle?  Seems to be more of a Java based website parsing site.  As mine is ASP and MSSQL driven there are severe limitations to what i can post into it.

Comment: After reviewing the resulting HTML code, after server parsing, shouldnt child DIV always expand the parent when the parent is `position:relative`?  I would expect this exclusive effect if the parent & child were both `position:absolute` but the parent is the container and the children are placed within the parent. I have a default declaration in css for `DIV` tags but only has one declaration `position:absolute`, which is overriden by the parent.

Comment: @STLRick not sure how fiddle will help with this as it is all jscript oriented and not asp.net.  Unless your talking about the resulting html which is bloated cause of the content acquired from the SQL Database.

Comment: @GoldBishop, if you want help with HTML and CSS, then you have to post your HTML and CSS. Not sure why that's so hard to understand. VieSource your output, cut out all the extraneous stuff, and post it to jsFiddle. Also, your Registration and QA divs are both position absolute. They do not inherit position relative just because their containing div has that set.

Comment: Also, why are you messing around with position absolute anyway? Your screen shot (ignoring the BG color) looks like a normal flow of elements. Perhaps you are giving your self unnecessary trouble?

Comment: @Graham Registration Div is the first Tag to be shown and when they click "submit" then it hides Registration and shows QA Div.

Comment: @Graham JSFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/qcDSW/1/ hope it helps but unsure if it will

Comment: Added CSS styles http://jsfiddle.net/qcDSW/2/

Comment: The jsfiddle you created isn't the same as the screen shot.

Comment: @Graham the containers are their....the table just has not been built.  The table described in the image is irrelevant to the problem itself.  the note is that the table itself is overflowing the parent (with black background).